# serializing array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm populating an array `nodevalues` with objects. It looks like this:

`nodevalues.push({id: this.id, left: left, right: right});`

This line is inside a `$.each()` iterator which iterates over some `li` nodes and also calculates the `left` and `right` values.

So I have an array with several objects who all look the same:[image: screen dump chrome console]

Is it possible to serialize this array to an url string for database storage using `jQuery.post()`?

Calling `$(nodevalues).serialize()` returns nothing and `$.param(nodevalues)` returns `undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined`...

Comment: Never do `$(this).attr('id')`. "this" is .each() is  the DOM element -> `this.id`

Comment: @Didier G I'm not sure I understand your comment. $(this) in jquery is this[0] in javascript. You should ALWAYS use $(this).attr('id') in jquery.

Comment: @DidierG. I think you're missing the point of my post. My question is how to serialize an array of objects. The code you mention works like it should.

Comment: @ZacL. It's just a comment, not an answer to your problem, i'm aware of that.

Comment: @ThomasClayson. Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/DryJW/1/)

Comment: @Didier G I understand what you mean now. $(this).attr('id') works just as well in your example however. Is there a significant advantage using `this.id`?

Comment: @ThomasClayson I understand it's better to use `this.id`, I've updated the code. Also have an idea about the real question? ;)

Comment: There is no "advantage". Its more efficient for sure. It also makes you have a better understanding of what is going on behind the scenes, from which you can only benefit.

Comment: Fair enough. :) Thanks, learnt something new today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) might do what you want

```
var dataString = jQuery.param(nodevalues);
```

It seems that param only works on objects, not arrays.

If you wrap your array in an object it works fine:

```
var nodevalues = [];

nodevalues.push({id: "node1", left: 1, right: 20});
nodevalues.push({id: "node2", left: 2, right: 10});
nodevalues.push({id: "node3", left: 3, right: 30});
nodevalues.push({id: "node4", left: 4, right: 40});

var data = { data: nodevalues };

alert($.param(data));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NELt/

Comment: Perfect! You just made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stringify function from the JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

you can supply the data as second argument to jquery.post()

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] );
```

jquery will serialize it for you.

Comment: You mean like this? `$.post('ajax/changenode.php', nodevalues);`
Results in:
Form data:
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined
undefined:undefined

Doesn't do the job!